# Modify the rxjs Observer to make another API request and return the same observer

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am making a HTTP request in Angular service which is returning the observable of this kind :

```
var response = of({
  status: "success",
  rings: [
    { pIds: [1, 2], pNames: [] },
    { pIds: [3, 4], pNames: [] },
  ],
});
```

Here **rings** is an array and each ring has an array of pIds and pNames.

I need to make another API call now to fetch pName from pId like this:

```
this.http.get<string>('principal',pId);  // this will return another observable which contains pName
```

How do I have my original observable with updated pNames array in each item of rings array ->

```
var result = response.pipe(???);  // make API call here and use suitable rxjs operators
result.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The output should be like this :

```
{
    status: "success",
    contents: [
      { pIds: [1, 2], pNames: ['NameOf1','NameOf2'] },
      { pIds: [3, 4], pNames: ['NameOf3','NameOf4'] },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `mergeMap`, `zip` and `map` does the trick.

```js
var result = response.pipe(
  mergeMap(response_ => {
    return zip(response_.rings.map(ring => {
      return zip(ring.pIds.map(pId => this.http.get<string>('principal', pId))).pipe(
        map(pNames => {
          ring.pNames = pNames;
          return ring;
        })
      );
    })).pipe(
      map(ringsWithNames => {
        response_.rings = ringsWithNames;
        return response_;
      })
    );
  })
);
```

You pipe your different operations in a `mergeMap` operator: this will allow you to work with additional `Observable` objects within your current one, `response`, and merge them together.

In the most nested `zip` operator, you look for the name for all `pIds`. Once you got them, you update your `ring.pNames` field with the `map` operator and return your new `ring`.

When all `pNames` are retrieved, the least nested `zip` operator will pipe all the `ring` objects with their `pNames` set (by the most nested `zip` operator): `ringsWithNames`. You then update the `response_.rings` field with those, and return your new `response_` object with the ring names set.

- `mergeMap`: allows you to start/take an `Observable` within another one and merge their results together;
- `zip`: take 1+ `Observable` and return their results in the same order once they all returned a result (if you give an array of Observable, you get an array of results as well, in the same order);
- `map`: update you response data in the way you want.

For further explanations, the [RxJS website](https://rxjs.dev/) is a nice source.

In particular, you should take a look at the [operator decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) which is a good starting point to choose which operator to use.